# Nvidia Gtx 960 blackscreen and loud noise, code 43:windows has stopped this device because it has reported prob

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, power-supply

Nvidia gtx690 blackscreen and loud noise(sometimes). code 43:windows has stopped this device because it has reported problem.

Currently i am using windows 10.

I tried many methods. Including unplug graphic card, Uninstall all nvdia software through DDU. Update Bios, set graphic primary to PCI-e. Update Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 Pro. Reformart. After keep restarting until i get my luck to boot up without blackscreen (more than 20 times). But, the device manager shows the error 43 Code on my graphic card. After uninstall the reinstall the driver. Restart computer, it went to blackscreen again. So I need to keep restart the pc again until I get my luck to boot up the computer without blackscreen. Any solution for this? Is it my psu too old or faulty? My psu is CM 460w (4 or 5 years).

Mobo - AS rock H97M-ITX/ac (4x3.0 usb, 2 x 2.0 usb),
Processor - Intel i5 4690s,
graphic card - ASUS Nvidia GTX 960 Itx,
RAM - 8 GB corsair DDR3 x 2,
SSD - 250 gb,
CM casing 110 - 120m front fan, 2x80mm side fan, 2 x 3.0 usb.

Never Overclocked Anything.

New update: Installed new PSU CM V650. Issue still same. Tried downgrade to two versions 362.00 and 358.91. Issue remain the same.

3/5/2016 Update: Tried downgrade windows 10 to 8.1 Pro. Primary graphic set to "onboard", install the drivers "362.00", it shows the VGA is working properly. However, once restart. The VGA having the same issue again. Keep repeating fix and restart.."Code 43 on VGA"... UNPLUG CABLE. Use laptop. VGA faulty or mobo faulty (PCI-e slot)?

Please note : i am able to use it for more than 8 months without any issue. Just that when gaming, the pc is quite hot until i need to use external fan to cool it down.

Need PROs advise and help :(  . Thanks.

Comment: There's some reports of issues with the latest driver - what driver version do you have installed?

Comment: latest driver from nvidia, Version: 364.72  WHQL, windows 10 64-bit , any version is good without issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Corrupted graphics, crashes, and noisy GPU fan after updating NVIDIA GeForce drivers to 364.72](http://superuser.com/questions/1071122/corrupted-graphics-crashes-and-noisy-gpu-fan-after-updating-nvidia-geforce-dri)

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading the driver from version: 364.72 - while somewhat alarmist - [this article](http://wccftech.com/nvidias-latest-game-ready-driver-allegedly-killing-gpus-plagued-issues/) suggests that that specific release is buggy. I believe I had 361 earlier and it was fine. I'm *personally* not having issues with 364 either, but my guess would be the previous version should be fine for now.

Comment: I tried downgraded to two version 362.00 and 358.91. Issue still not yet resolved. No luck here.