# Corrupted graphics, crashes, and noisy GPU fan after updating NVIDIA GeForce drivers to 364.xx

Tags: drivers, bsod, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, community-faq-proposed

I recently updated the drivers for my NVIDIA GeForce video card to version 364.72 (or other version in the 364.xx series), and I'm now experiencing issues such as the following:

- Games or other graphically intensive applications crash or hang
- I get BSODs that are associated with the graphics driver, e.g. `nvlddmkm.sys` or `dxgkrnl.sys`
- Graphical glitches such as missing or misplaced text or icons, display corruption, or a black screen occur
- The graphics driver crashes regularly, with the message "Display driver [...] has stopped responding and has recovered."
- The fan on my graphics card spins up to high speed, or the card makes excessive noise

Reinstalling the graphics driver did not help. What's going on?

> *This question comes up often and the answers are usually the same. This post is meant to provide a definitive, canonical answer for this problem. Feel free to edit the answer to add additional details.*

Comment: Rollback to the previous driver

Comment: I know of at least one other question that can be closed but answered because of this question.  Good Job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 slow at opening media files](http://superuser.com/questions/1061528/windows-7-slow-at-opening-media-files)

Comment: Reviewers: this *is* the canonical question. Please don't flag or vote to close this question; instead, the others should be closed as duplicates of this question. http://superuser.com/questions/1061528/windows-7-slow-at-opening-media-files#comment1510559_1061528

Comment: what model is your graphics card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The 364.xx drivers are buggy. It's best to use version 362.00 until NVIDIA addresses these issues.

- [WCCFtech](http://wccftech.com/nvidias-latest-game-ready-driver-allegedly-killing-gpus-plagued-issues/) has reported that many users are experiencing serious problems with the 364.72 drivers, ranging from crashes and hangs to **outright hardware failure** (i.e. the card is bricked). These issues don't seem to affect everyone, but it's best not to take the risk.
- Several other versions in the 364 series are affected with similar bugs (though not necessarily of the same severity). The last driver prior to the 364 series is [362.00](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/99202/en-us), which has been problem-free for most users.