# Computer UI is getting distorted and everything stops working

Tags: windows, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

[image: Desktop Screenshot]

While using my desktop PC,the UI suddenly gets messed up as in the screenshot and audio,mouse,keyboard stops working.After I restart my CPU,it works normally.This happens once in a day or two.

I dont know whats causing the issue.Also how should i fix it ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks a lot like your GPU is dying, or your drivers are buggy - What sort of hardware is this?

Comment: intel i3 processor,2gb RAM,ATI HD4300 graphic card

Comment: This sounds like a very old computer to me. Perhaps you should buy a new PC?

Answer (score 2):

This is typically caused by a failing GPU or video memory, although software issues can cause similar glitches.

- First, try to update your graphics drivers. This is particularly likely to be an issue if you have an NVIDIA GeForce card and are running a 364 series driver; see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1071122/corrupted-graphics-crashes-and-noisy-gpu-fan-after-updating-nvidia-geforce-dri) for more information. If updating the drivers does not help, or you're already running the latest drivers, then you're probably experiencing a hardware failure.

  - If you're using a dedicated graphics card, see if the problem goes away when you remove the card and fall back on integrated graphics, or use a different graphics card. If it does, you'll need to replace the graphics card.
  - If you're using integrated graphics, run a memory test program like [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) to determine if it's the system RAM or the integrated graphics processor itself. If the memory test returns no errors, it's the IGP and you'll need to replace the CPU. Otherwise, you'll need to replace the RAM.

---

Your comments indicate that you're running a very old computer—the graphics card dates to 2008 and 2 GB is very little memory by today's standards. You may want to consider buying a new PC instead of replacing the failing part.